# Is it possible to change IntelliJ's code generation template for equals() and hashCode()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation

Is it possible to change the code generation template for `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

I would like the generated code to use the Java 7 `Objects` class for theses methods.

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56007.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Awesome, I don't suppose you could do anything about getting youTrack issues index by Google?

Comment: Search engine indexing is [intentionally disabled](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/robots.txt) on YouTrack site.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of [release 14.1](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/intellij-idea-14-1-ships-with-nextgen-of-code-generation/) of the Ultimate Edition it is possible to customize the Code generation template of equals()/hashCode() without the use of any third party plugin.

Press "Alt + Insert" (Generate...), choose "equals() and hashCode()" and you will be able to select one of the predefined templates or a customized template of your own.

[image: "Generate equals() and hashCode()" dialog]

[image: Edit "equals() and hashCode()" Velocity templates]

Comment: Nice. Do you know where I can find a velocity template for generating equals and hashcode Eclipse style?

Comment: The trouble with this example is that it's the #addClassInstance macro that I'm not happy with, and it's used by all the templates. It gives me "if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;" but I want it to give me "if (!(o instanceof MyClass)) return false;". Does anyone know how to edit this macro? (I tried removing it, but I need a macro for the class name, and I don't know what it is.)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE: have a look at the answer from @datentyp. Leaving mine for those stuck on the old versions**

There are plugins to allow this.
Please have a look at this ones:

> http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6875?pr=idea
>
> http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7244?pr=idea

They are opensource so you can amend them if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: As of version 14.1 this is supported.**

Apparently this functionality does not exist.

There is a request for it though, see: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56007

Answer (score 2):

Yes **it is** possible, but with some small hack. Locate your idea.jar file in app folder. Look inside and find files like:

- apacheEqualsBuilder3.vm
- apacheHashCodeBuilder3.vm

and other .vm files..

These template files reuse some macros from equalsHelper.vm.

Change these files inside JAR carefully as you like restart app and check result in Idea under

*generate->equals() and hashCode()->Template (... three dots on the right)->read only preview on the right side.*

I think installing update of Idea may overwrite this JAR with your
custom template changes.

It works! Checked in Idea 15. Enjoy. :-)

Comment: I use this method in combination with previous to fine tune my generator templates for equals() and hashCode().
The code in "*.vm" files is written on Apache Velocity(http://velocity.apache.org) template language.