# Customize equals / hashCode in Idea's "Generate..."

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation

When creating a new class, it is useful to generate all the boilerplate by IDE (unless e.g. Lombok is used, of course). I tried to do it with IntelliJ Idea and I didn't like the equals and `hashCode` methods.

In fact, not even Idea itself liked the equals method. The code inspection says that the statement can be simplified. Well, it looks slightly better after applying Simplify `n+1` times where `n` is amount of fields used in the methods, but it is still not the intended result.

`Objects.equals(objA, objB)` and `Objects.hash(Object...)` are considered best practice where I work. Is it possible to modify the templates used in Quick Generation feature?

If not, is there any update planned to enhance its behavior so that it at least passes inspections?

Comment: Technically this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362721/is-it-possible-to-change-intellijs-code-generation-template-for-equals-and-ha). The answers in there contain links to plugins that allow it, and a link to the feature request for it in IntelliJ core (I didn't investigate the validity of those links). You could use the plugins while you wait for 14.1, or join the EAP.

Comment: I looked at the similar questions while typing this and the question you mentioned didn't appear there. It even has the same tags, I guess I should practice my searching skills. Anyway, it seems I got an answer that is not mentioned there - I'm looking forward to 14.1

Comment: It could also be that Stack Overflow's search isn't perfect (*hides from SO devs*)

Comment: Quite interesting that the older question only mentioned plugins until March 15. Not surprising there is a downvote if it's technically a duplicate, but another question being downvoted in the very same minute sounds more like some personal vendetta, however feeble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest IDEA 14.1 EAP (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP) contains this possibility, please try it.