# Generate Kotlin equals and hashcode methods from Intellij with java 7 methods

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, code-generation, equals

I want to generate **Kotlin** equal and hashcodes using the Java 7 methods just as we [usually do for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362721/is-it-possible-to-change-intellijs-code-generation-template-for-equals-and-ha). Let's assume that converting the class to a data class is not an option.

In IntelliJ, for Java, I can choose my Equal and HashCode template to implement it with the much more elegant and compact Java 7 version.

[image]

However in Kotlin I am redirected directly to a menu to choose the properties.

This is a **Java** generated one:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Delete delete = (Delete) o;
    return var == delete.var && Objects.equals(foo, delete.foo);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(foo, var);
}
```

This is a Kotlin one:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) return true
    if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

    other as Delete

    if (foo != other.foo) return false
    if (`var` != other.`var`) return false

    return true
}

override fun hashCode(): Int {
    var result = foo.hashCode()
    result = 31 * result + `var`
    return result
}
```

You may appreciate that the Kotlin version is coding the number hash with prime numbers itself. That is because it is not using *Objects.hash* or *Objects.equals*

**Note**: I am usinng Intellij 2021.1.3 Ultimate

*Update*:

I have my kotlin target version set to Java 11 with:

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
          <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <compilerPlugins>
              <plugin>spring</plugin>
            </compilerPlugins>
            <jvmTarget>${java.version}</jvmTarget>
```

I had also updated the main config here:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually checked what equals and hashCode functions it generates? I'm not seeing a difference (aside from the obvious Kotlin vs. Java syntax)

Comment: Good point @Jacob. I have edited the question to include the information. It is exactly the same Java class after migrating to Kotlin my the automatic Intellij option

Comment: By default, the Kotlin compiler targets Java 1.6 bytecode. Have you tried changing your Kotlin compiler target to JVM 1.7 or later?

Comment: Good point @user31601 but I have it set to 11

Comment: Created a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19340

Comment: Thanks you very much @MargaritaBobova